# How to use Google spreadsheet data in my website page?

Tags: google-api, google-sheets

Data In google spreadsheet is like

EmpId  |  EmpName
1      |  John
2      |  Jerry

---

I want to display these data in my webiste. (Say www.example.com/employeeList.html)
But I do not want to publish the above spreadsheet, only i want to fetch the record
when a user will access the above page link.

Note : The document will be in private mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing it as a JSON or XML. I don't know much about how the API retrieves the information but there are some tools that could help you with that. Links coming soon.

Do you prefer any specific format?

If the document is private, some kind of authentication must be in place to retrieve the locked data and then figure out how to parse it, or both at a time.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply.
If I am publishing the document, then I am receiving the data. But in this way it is open for public and any one can view that document with the link. 
So I want to make it private, and at the same time I want to get the data from the document.

Comment: Can you please give a little bit more idea about this?

Comment: If you are still making it private you will have to get a certificate to access it, in other words to authenticate as a user. You could cache it while it is "public" but you would not be able to update it after making it private. Baign able to use the link is helpful since you ca have a server pull the file and parse the information in whatever format you need.